# How to merge query-results/objects by id in an array in a React app using Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query result from a Firestore snapshot which is basically chat messages from 3 people:

```
{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:13:59 am", name: "John Doe", email: "john@example.com", uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "Hello"}

{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:14:01 am", name: "John Doe", email: "john@example.com", uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "World"}

{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:14:03 am", name: "John Doe", email: "john@example.com", uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "How are you?"}


{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:10 am", name: "Jane Jones", email: "jane@example.com", uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "I am good, you?"}

{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:14 am", name: "Jane Jones", email: "jane@example.com", uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "Nice weather"}

{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:17 am", name: "Jane Jones", email: "jane@example.com", uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "See you!"}


{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:20 am", name: "Tom Adams", email: "tom@example.com", uid: "sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9", content: "Finally, spring time!"}

{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:24 am", name: "Tom Adams", email: "tom@example.com", uid: "sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9", content: "I agree!"}

{timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:31 am", name: "Tom Adams", email: "tom@example.com", uid: "sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9", content: "Let's do it!"}
```

What I want to achieve is placing the results in an key/value object like the following:

```
    {
    
    uid: pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9
    
    data: [  
    {timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:13:59 am", name: "John Doe", email: "john@example.com", uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "Hello"}
    
    {timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:14:01 am", name: "John Doe", email: "john@example.com", uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "World"}
    
    {timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:14:03 am", name: "John Doe", email: "john@example.com", uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "How are you?"}
    
    ]}
    
    or 
    
    {
    
    uid: cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9
    
   data: [
    {timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:10 am", name: "Jane Jones", email: "jane@example.com", uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "I am good, you?"}
    
    {timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:14 am", name: "Jane Jones", email: "jane@example.com", uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "Nice weather"}
    
    {timestamp: "October 25th 2020, 11:15:17 am", name: "Jane Jones", email: "jane@example.com", uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9", content: "See you!"}
    ]
    
    }
```

Comment: Please add the following information to your question: The code for the query you are performin. What have you tried so far? Are you using the Firebase JS SDK or the Firebase React Native SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const rawResults = [
{
  name: "John Doe",
  uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9",
  content: "Hello"
},
{
  name: "John Doe",
  uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9",
  content: "World"
},
{
  name: "John Doe",
  uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9",
  content: "How are you?"
},
{
  name: "Jane Jones",
  uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9",
  content: "I am good, you?"
},
{
  name: "Jane Jones",
  uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9",
  content: "Nice weather"
},
{
  name: "Jane Jones",
  uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9",
  content: "See you!"
},
{
  name: "Tom Adams",
  uid: "sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9",
  content: "Finally, spring time!"
},
{
  name: "Tom Adams",
  uid: "sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9",
  content: "I agree!"
},
{
  name: "Tom Adams",
  uid: "sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9",
  content: "Let's do it!"
}
];
```

step 1:
the following will give you an object (parent object), the object keys will be the unique uids, and the value for each of the object keys will be an array containing objects that share the same uid

```
const filteredResults = rawResults.reduce((prev, current) => {
const key = current.uid;
const keyExist = prev.hasOwnProperty(key);

  if (keyExist) {
    prev[key].push(current);
  } else {
    prev[key] = new Array(current);
  }

  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(filteredResults); 
// {
//   cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
//   pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9:  (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
//   sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
// {
```

step 2:
map over the filteredResults object to get an array of objects, each object has two properties: uid and data: (array of objects that share the same uid)

```
const mappedArr = Object.keys(filteredResults).map((key) => {
  return {
    uid: key,
    data: filteredResults[key]
  };
});

console.log(mappedArr);
// (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
// 0: {uid: "pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9", data: Array(3)}
// 1: {uid: "cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9", data: Array(3)}
// 2: {uid: "sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9", data: Array(3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with one step

```
const yourList = [
  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:13:59 am',
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    uid: 'pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9',
    content: 'Hello',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:14:01 am',
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    uid: 'pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9',
    content: 'World',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:14:03 am',
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    uid: 'pUNIrnZaMWXC7Dai5aHapZFeght9',
    content: 'How are you?',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:15:10 am',
    name: 'Jane Jones',
    email: 'jane@example.com',
    uid: 'cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9',
    content: 'I am good, you?',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:15:14 am',
    name: 'Jane Jones',
    email: 'jane@example.com',
    uid: 'cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9',
    content: 'Nice weather',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:1L5:17 am',
    name: 'Jane Jones',
    email: 'jane@example.com',
    uid: 'cARRYrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFeght9',
    content: 'See you!',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:15:20 am',
    name: 'Tom Adams',
    email: 'tom@example.com',
    uid: 'sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9',
    content: 'Finally, spring time!',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:15:24 am',
    name: 'Tom Adams',
    email: 'tom@example.com',
    uid: 'sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9',
    content: 'I agree!',
  },

  {
    timestamp: 'October 25th 2020, 11:15:31 am',
    name: 'Tom Adams',
    email: 'tom@example.com',
    uid: 'sVOUIrnZaMWXC9Dai5aHapZFejtr9',
    content: "Let's do it!",
  },
];
const result = [];
yourList.forEach((element) => {
  const index = result.findIndex((value) => value.uid === element.uid);
  if (index > -1) {
    result[index].data.push({
      timestamp: element.timestamp,
      email: element.email,
      content: element.content,
    });
  } else {
    result.push({
      uid: element.uid,
      data: [
        {
          timestamp: element.timestamp,
          email: element.email,
          content: element.content,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
});

console.log(result);
```